# Gstreamer Saving Image / Video on the receiver side

Tags: android, gstreamer, live-streaming

I use this following codes for live streaming using gstreamer but i don't know how to save video/image on receiver side. Anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance.

**Sender code :** *"raspivid -t 999999 -h 720 -w 1080 -fps 25 -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-0.10 -v fdsrc fd=0 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.2.1 port=5000"*

**Receiver code :** *"udpsrc port=5000 caps=\"application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, sprop-parameter-sets=\\"J2QAFKwrQLj/LwDxImo\\=\\,KO4fLA\\=\\=\\"\", payload=96\" ! queue ! rtph264depay  ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink sync=false"*

Comment: What format do you want to save it as?

Comment: Any format.. but it has to play in android phone using Android Media Player.. If possible can u please help in this..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
"udpsrc port=5000 caps=application/x-rtp buffer-size=100000 ! rtph264depay ! tee name=splitter ! ffdec_h264 ! queue ! autovideosink sync=false splitter. ! queue ! mpegpsmux name=mux ! filesink location=/../../some.mpeg"
```

Comment: Felix can u help in selection of codec.. Since i am able to save the video file but not able to play using Android Media Player..

Comment: use different player, like MX player. It'll be OK. If you want to play file in standard android player you have to experiment.

Comment: Felix can u help me in saving only image(or capturing image) while streaming live..

Comment: Can advice you to make two pipelines on transmitter and two pipelines on receiver with different ports for video-pare and photo-pare, and some simple programme to switch from one to another. Or you can use Dynamic pipelines (learn more with GST_DOCS_ chapter 19, as I remember ). And the hardest way, I think, to parse video-stream with gst instruments and catch out the frame. Sorry, can't tell you more concrete((

Comment: Hi.. The above code is for rasp pi camera broad.. can anyone help with commands for usb webcam connected to raspberry pi..